# Are 'bloody', 'bloodied', and 'bleeding' all okay in this context?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, word-choice

> A **bloody/ bloodied/ bleeding** Seth ran after the robber.

Are they all correct and natural if Seth has blood on himself?

Answer (score 3):

They are not the same, though they are all correct.

"Bloody" and "bloodied" just mean he has blood on him. It could be his own, or the robber's, or someone else's.

"Bleeding" means that Seth has injuries that are currently causing him to shed blood.

Comment: does it also mean all of them can be used with a person?

Comment: Yes, all those adjectives can be used of a person, with the differences that Mary explains.